# Helm: Pluck nested value from values.yaml in helpers template

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I have the below in values.yaml

```
edir:
 foo:
   stg: A
   prd: B
   dev: C
 bar:
   stg: E
   prd: F
   dev: G
 _default:
   dev: Z
```

The values of `foo` and `bar` are the site of the application environment. They get set in `.Values.site`

And the `stg`, `prd` and `dev` are the kubernetes namespaces.
How do I pull the values based on environment and namespaces?

I have tried

`(pluck .Values.site .Release.Namespace .Values.edir | first | default .Values.edir._default.dev)`

The above is wrong.

I have tried with dig as well,

`(dig .Values.edir .Values.site .Release.Namespace .Values.edir._default.dev)`

This doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you use a separate Helm values file per environment, and have your chart's `values.yml` just have the default values?  And then you can just refer to `.Values.edir` and get a string value, without having to pick it out of a multiply-nested tree of values?

Comment: Yeah I took your advice and did what you said..made my life easier. Thank you!